# Mac zsh script failing due to bad interpreter

Tags: bash, macos, zsh

I have created the following script to check for awdl0 as this interface causes network issues, but is used for seamless apple device features.

I saved this as a .command file and ensured to put permissions to 755.
Initially i tried this as a bash script, but temrinal gave an error as asked to use zsh. I changed to zsh and I am still experiencing issues with a bad interpreter errors.

I am running ths file from the desktop of an elevated user.
I have run 'which zsh' to enusre location
zsh runs locally

I created the script from Windows via Notepad++. I checked for UTF-8 without BOM, I checked for line return formatting.

For good measure I also ran a `sed -i -e 's/\r$//'` against it.

Script:

```
#!/bin/zsh

interface="awdl0"

# Greet the user
echo "Hello $(whoami)!"

# Check for sudo privileges
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "This script requires elevated privileges. Please enter your password:"

    for attempt in {1..3}; do
        read -s password

        if echo "$password" | sudo -S true; then
            break
        else
            if [ "$attempt" -eq 3 ]; then
                echo "Incorrect password. Exiting."
                exit 1
            else
                echo "Incorrect password. Please try again. Attempts left: $((3 - attempt))."
            fi
        fi
    done
fi

# Check the current status of the network interface
status=$(ifconfig "$interface" | grep "status" | awk '{print $2}')

echo "Current status of $interface: $status"

if [ "$status" == "active" ]; then
    echo "AirDrop and other seamless Apple functions are active."
    echo "Wi-Fi may experience unexpected latency causing issues with streaming and other internet services."
elif [ "$status" == "inactive" ]; then
    echo "AirDrop and other seamless Apple functions are inactive."
    echo "Wi-Fi will be stable, but you may experience interruptions in certain Apple functions."
else
    echo "Invalid status detected. Please check the network interface."
    exit 1
fi

# Ask the user if they want to change the status
read -p "Do you want to change the status of $interface? (y/n): " choice

if [ "$choice" == "y" ]; then
    # Toggle the status of the network interface
    if [ "$status" == "active" ]; then
        echo "$password" | sudo -S ifconfig "$interface" down
        new_status="inactive"
    elif [ "$status" == "inactive" ]; then
        echo "$password" | sudo -S ifconfig "$interface" up
        new_status="active"
    else
        echo "Invalid status detected. Please check the network interface."
        exit 1
    fi

    echo "$interface status has been flipped from $status to $new_status."
else
    echo "No changes made. Exiting."
fi
```

Comment: `head -n 1 yourscript | hexdump -C` is a place to start to see if there's something other than a carriage return on the shebang line. Also, please copy-and-paste the _exact_ error, don't just describe it.

Comment: Separately, `echo "$password" | sudo -S ...` is generally something you should do only when you have no other choices, and that's rarely the case. For example, one can have `/etc/sudoers` contain a line that allows _passwordless_ access to run `/sbin/ifconfig * up` and `/sbin/ifconfig * down` -- or you can instruct users to use `sudo` to start your script, instead of having the script itself use `sudo` at all.

Comment: BTW, better form to use `[ "$x" = y ]` rather than `[ "$x" == y ]` -- `==` is an extension, whereas `=` is backwards-compatible with POSIX and pre-POSIX tooling.

Comment: Also, `grep | awk` is basically always unnecessary; `awk '/status/ { print $2 }'` does the work of `grep status` built into the awk command.

Comment: (btw, the terminal message recommending zsh instead of bash on MacOS doesn't apply to scripts; it's a warning only giving advice about _interactive_ interpreter selection [because Apple is unwilling to agree to the GPLv3 license modern bash is under, they ship an extremely old version nobody should use]; if you're using an interactive interpreter to run a script, something is very, very wrong).

Comment: Really hard to see how all that code only generates *"bad interpreter errors"*. Please update your question to show the exact text of the error message. what happens if you make a test :`printf '#!/bin/zsh\necho "Hello World"\n'> ./myTestScript ; chmod 755 ./myTestScript ; ./myTestScript` ?

Comment: You need to show us the actual command you ran and the literal error message. Writing "I am still experiencing issues with a bad interpreter errors" isn't helpful.

Comment: _bad interpreter_ in most cases refer to a problem with your #! line. As a test, I would first run the script with `/bin/zsh YOUR_SCRIPT`, in which case the #! line is just treated as comment with no deeper meaning. Does this work?